# Is there an efficient way to assert that all the elements of a PageObject are visible?

Tags: pageobjects, nightwatch.js

It's great how you can describe key elements of a page using the `elements` object in `nightwatch`'s `PageObject`.

A very basic test of "is the page rendered correctly?" seems to consist of a string of asserts that every element is visible:

```
 'Does it look right' : function (browser) {
      browser.page.welcome()
         .navigate()
         .assert.title('My App')
         .assert.visible('@header')
         .assert.visible('@usernameField')
         .assert.visible('@passwordField')
         .assert.visible('@forgotPasswordLink')
         .assert.visible('@signupButton')
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You could try to make `assert.visible` in the loop.

Comment: Indeed, but ... how do I get the list of page object elements?   Maybe this is the "actual" question!

Comment: Is  it possible to iterate here on `elements`?

Comment: I think that this is one of the questions I need a clue about.  It'd be easy enough to try, and I will, but how to chain the asserts in a loop?  It seems like a case for a funky `yield` or something like that, but I don't have my head around that yet!

Comment: If  it would be possible to get elements try to apply there forEach with function, where you will do the assertion.

Comment: But they need to be chained to the page instantiation?

Comment: ... which is hard to see how to do in a loop?

Comment: Wait, I made a mistake :) I think that one assert should be enough inside the loop without chaining. Just put inside the assert element, which will be the part of the collection you loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script with your custom logic and then test against that

```
    var script = function () {
      //some logic or query selector test
      return foo;
    };

   module.exports = {
  'Test PCC': function (browser) {

    var test;

    browser
      url('foo')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .execute(script, [], function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        test = response.value;
      })

      //assert. test is something
      .end();
  }
};
```